# How to run a 32-bit .NET application in a 64-bit environment?

Tags: .net, 64-bit

We developed a C# application using the .NET Framework 2.0 which works fine in 32-bit computers. But when I run my application in a 64-bit environment, it crashes.

I need to make my application to run in 64-bit environment.

How do I do this?

Comment: We'll need rather more information than that. Does it use P/Invoke? Have you isolated it to a specific area of code?

Answer (score 9):

You could compile it for x86 instead of any cpu that way it will run against 32bit librarys on a 64bit windows.

Or swap 32bit librarys for 64bit when installning on 64bit windows. Among other some Sqlite dlls are specific for 32/64 bit

Comment: +1 This simple solution saved me having to support x86 and x64 builds in parallel! Wish I could upvote many times!!

Answer (score 6):

If you are on Windows you shall use **CorFlags** Conversion Tool (*CorFlags.exe*). This way you might enforce application/dll's to run in 32/64 bit space.  Details and examples of use are available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(VS.80).aspx.

Comment: This will work but if you build on a build server, you should really check your build targets and dependencies for x86. Setting your project up to build properly for your target environments will make more sense in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

In the build settings for you project set the platform target to x86 instead of Any CPU. This will solve problems where your project has "hidden" dependendencies on 32 bit subsystems that are not available in 64 bit. Your application will then run in the 32 bit susbsystem on 64 bit Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what looks to be a nice solution if you are looking to avoid recompilation.  Note it does require a change to each target machine.

> If you have a 64 bit machine and want to run a .NET application that
>   only works with the 32 bit CLR you would have to make changes to the
>   .NET framework on your machine
>
> Set the .NET framework to load the CLR in WOW mode through this
>   command
>
> Open up command prompt and type this command
>
> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Ldr64.exe SetWow
>
> Now you should be able to run apps that use only the .NET 32 bit CLR.
>
> To revert back to the default 64 bit framework run
>
> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Ldr64.exe Set64

([source](http://techdhaan.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/run-32-bit-net-applications-on-64-bit-machines/))

Answer (score 2):

Just expanding on Fredrik Leijon's answer above, I think this is what you are after.

It will tell both 64 and 32 bit windows to run your application on the 32 bit environment.

Remeber to do the same for your 'Release' configuration.

[image]

This will in turn update your *.csproj file for MSBuild to pick up as follows (check the `<PlatformTarget/>` element below):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
 <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
 <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
 <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
 <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I my case it was enough to compile the main assembly (.exe) of my application especially for "x86". The other assemblies (.dll) are compiled with "Any CPU".

Our application then works fine on 32Bit and 64Bit systems.

Answer (score 0):

It should just run unless you're referencing libraries that are specifically only available for 32bit (Jet DB drivers are one example) or unless you've told your compiler to compile your application to 32bit only.

What does the crash say?

Comment: If the compiler is told to compile to 32 bit only, then in fact it *should* work, and is in fact probably an acceptable fix for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it Windows/ASP.NET application?

If it is an ASP.NET application. you can run only 32/64-bit modes at the same time.
For doing this,

Case 1. you need to `Enable32bitApplication` on the application pool in the IIS.
          Then reset the IIS.

Case 2. Check for the corresponding DLL in regedit.

If it is windows based, run this command from Visual Studio prompt,

```
CorFlags.exe TheApp.exe /32BIT+ //Enables 32 bit application.
```

Comment: Enabling 32 bit on the apppool in IIS is enough.  Trying to use CorFlags works great, until you find the assembly is signed, then it fails.